# CoreMIDI MIDIInputPortCreateWithProtocol problem with more than 2 keys pressed

Tags: ios, swift, midi, coremidi

I'm studying CoreMIDI to connect a musical keyboard to get keys pressed and mount chord.

After few days I don't know why sometimes the block from MIDIInputPortCreateWithProtocol not receive some events.

**For example:**

- If I press one key an release it, the events received normally.
- If I press two keys simultaneously sometimes I receive two events with one packet in each one or receive one event with two packets, but sometimes one key event pressed not reach the block, registering just one key pressed or released.
- If I press three key normally one event or one packet from one key not reach the block

But when I press one key separately and not release it I receive all keys pressed.

My MIDIInputPortCreateWithProtocol code is

```
func createInputPort(midiClient: MIDIClientRef) {
        MIDIInputPortCreateWithProtocol(midiClient, "Input Port" as CFString, MIDIProtocolID._1_0, &self.inputPort) {  [weak self] eventList, srcConnRefCon in
            print("=== event received")

            guard let strogSelf = self else {
                return
            }
            
            let midiEventList: MIDIEventList = eventList.pointee
            var packet = midiEventList.packet
            
            for _ in 1...midiEventList.numPackets {
                let words = Mirror(reflecting: packet.words).children
                for word in words {
                    guard let uint32 = word.value as? UInt32,
                          uint32 > 0 else { return }
                    
                    let messageType = (uint32 & 0xF0000000) >> 28
                    
                    if (messageType == 0x02) {
                        let status = (uint32 & 0x00FF0000) >> 16
                        let midiCommand = status >> 4                        
                        if midiCommand == strogSelf.NOTE_ON {
                            strogSelf.noteAdd(noteInfo: MidiPacket(data: uint32, command: midiCommand, timeStamp: packet.timeStamp))
                            break
                        } else if midiCommand == strogSelf.NOTE_OFF {
                            strogSelf.noteRemove(noteInfo: MidiPacket(data: uint32, command: midiCommand, timeStamp: packet.timeStamp))
                            break
                        }
                    }
                }
                packet = MIDIEventPacketNext(&packet).pointee
            }
        }
        
        MIDIPortConnectSource(self.inputPort, self.endpoint ?? MIDIGetSource(MIDIGetNumberOfSources()-1), &self.connRefCon)
}
```

The ideia is receive all key pressed like in garageband.

If I open garageband together with my project, when I press three keys simultaneously the garage band detect all of them and my project sometimes not.

Anyone have some ideia what is happen here?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't know but I think a general reference application that is properly coded would be a great start. I'm not sure how to fix your code or what's wrong with it.

Comment: @WarrenP the problem is the type of byte reach when I press a key, so it's easier use AudioKit

Comment: Found this sample app did you notice it?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremidi/midi_services/incorporating_midi_2_into_your_apps?changes=_1

There's a downloadable sample app ^

Comment: @WarrenP I'm using this code but it get just one kind of byte and the correct is verify what is in packet and the size of object byte, the AudioKit is easier and they solved this problem.